# Is it possible to count the number of surjective or injective functions with no fixed points?

Tags: combinatorics

Is it possible to count the number of surjective or injective functions with no fixed points?

Suppose we're give a function $f:\left [ n \right ]\rightarrow \left [ k \right ]$ where $n<k$. How many injective functions are there with no fixed points? 
Similar question for counting surjective functions when $n>k$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: do you find it easier to count the number of injective functions with $f(1) = 1$? Or the number of injective functions with $f(1) = 1$ and $f(2) = 2$?

Use the inclusion-exclusion principle to determine the number of functions with at least one fixpoint from this.